# Not able to access a Windows 8 binary from the command prompt even when PATH is set properly

Tags: windows-8, path, command-line

I am currently seeing a weird problem in Windows 8 installed on my laptop. I have copied "apache maven" to the C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation folder. I have set the `JAVA_HOME`, `M2_HOME` environment variables as per instructions and added the Maven bin folder to the path.

```
C:\Users\vikram>echo %M2_HOME%

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-2.2.1

C:\Users\vikram>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin;C:\Perl64\sit
e\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\Dr
iver;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Clie
nt\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\
WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Compon
ents\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Pro
gram Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program File
s (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\I
ntel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;
C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Progr
am Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache
-ant-1.8.4\bin
```

But when I try to access "mvn" at the command prompt, it gives me the error as follows:

```
C:\Users\vikram>mvn
```

> 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

The only thing that I did differently is installed cygwin recently. From cygwin, I am able to access the "mvn" bin

```
vikram@olympus ~
$ mvn --version
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-2.2.1/boot/
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/apache-maven-2.2.1/boot/
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 12:16:01-0700)
Java version: 1.7.0_15
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8" version: "6.2" arch: "amd64" Family: "windows"
```

Why am I not able to access the "mvn" binary from the Windows command prompt?

Comment: Gawd, I *hate* Intel software.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about), started as an Administrator, and put these variables into my System path, and this problem went away.

For some reason, when I added the the JDK, JRE, and Maven bin folders to my Path through the Windows utility, it didn't work. Rapid Environment Editor told me that the variables were not valid or I did not have access to them. Windows 8 seems to be really picky about administrator rights and I guess they didn't think that through very well.

Just be sure to start Rapid Environment Editor as an administrator, and re-open your command windows when you save your changes.